# Editing attributes in ArcMap causes conversion of arcs to densified lines unintentionally

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, postgresql, convert, densify

I am using postgresql GDB for storing and managing polyline feature classes through arcmap but when I create arc feature along with filling any attributes the arc is being converted to a densified straight polyline unintentionally.

[image: densified straight line]

It is noticeable that if I do not fill attributes when editor is started, arc structure (just 2 end points) is being preserved and saved as well.

[image: no filling or modifying attributes]

I found that *gdb_geomattr_data* column is a repository for curve parameters but my feature class (which has been registered as versioned) not showing this trend! I got completely confused.